# Replace string with spans containing each character

Tags: html, string, append

I would like to **replace the content** of an h1 element **containing a character chain** with the same chain but **each character should be wrapped in a span**.

That seemed easy enough to me, but I maybe underestimated it.

Here's what I tried (css only for debug purposes) :

```js
var titleLen = $("#title").length - 1;
for (i=0; i<titleLen; i++) {
 letter = $("#title").charAt(i);
 $("#title").append("<span>" + letter + "</span>");
};
```

```css
h1 span {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h1 id=title>
Hello World !
</h1>
```

It isn't working but I can't find the problem. Any help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Part of the reason your current code isn't working is that you're calling `length` and `charAt` on the DOM element instead of on its contents -- but even with that corrected you're modifying the contents of the div at each step of the iteration, so the second `charAt` would wind up reaching part of the span you just inserted instead of the second character of the original string.   (Edit: I've just realize this description isn't quite right; you would wind up with a span-wrapped copy after the original text, because you append instead of replacing.)

Here are a couple of different ways you could use your original algorithm:

```js
// keep a copy of the original string and work from that:
var title = $("#title").html();
$('#title').html('');
for (i = 0; i < title.length; i++) {
  letter = title.charAt(i);
  $("#title").append("<span>" + letter + "</span>");
};


// Alternatively, build a string and dump it into the DOM all at once:
/*
let output = '';
for (i = 0; i < $('#title').html().length; i++) {
  letter = $('#title').html().charAt(i);
  output +="<span>" + letter + "</span>";
};
$('#title').html(output);
*/
```

```css
h1 span {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h1 id=title>
  Hello World !
</h1>
```

Or a simpler way to do this is to split the string into an array for each character, then use 'join' to include the span tags:

```js
$('#title').html(
  '<span>' + 
  $('#title').html().split('').join('</span><span>') +
  '</span>'
)
```

```css
h1 span {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h1 id=title>
Hello World !
</h1>
```